# Appointment Slot Booking Using FSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, fscalendar

Problem
Current time Comprasion with Array of Time
like [12:00,01:00,02:00,03:00,04:00,05:00,6:00]

Actually, I am Creating an Appointment Page using FSCalendar and CollectionView Cell For time Slots.
I want to be set to disable Time-Slots If the current time pass Array of some time but time slots will work in future Selection Always.

For example, my current time is 02:00 pm the show 12:00, 01:00 De-Selectable.

**Used --> FSCalender.**

[image]

**Used --> CollectionView Cell** for Showing Time like [12:00,01:00,02:00,03:00,04:00,05:00,6:00]

Comment: Can you help us to understand your view controller code. Collection view for time selection is made by you, right? That's is not a part of FSCalendar?

Comment: i am Implemented FsCalender Code and Take Array of string the return array data in collection view Cell.

Comment: yes, i am implemented my side collection view for time selection. Just take array of string. @Darshan

Comment: I will check and get back to you.

Comment: @Darshan please contact me my email- deviossam@gmail.com